# Where-clause in LINQ to SQL Sum() function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
// get number of sheep in DataTable by counting UID's
Double n = DataTableContainingSheep.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => (Int32)r["sheepId"])
```

What I if want to count only the black sheep in the DataTable? Is there any way I can fit a select-clause into the `Sum()` function?

Comment: Why would a table contaning a list of Sheep contain a field called "Sheep", why would that be a numeric type?  I can understand you wanting to provide a simple example of what you want to do but that simplification ought to make sense.

Comment: Point taken. Updated my question. Stack Overflow encourages exactly this sort of behavior--You should just have gone ahead and edited my post yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
Double n =
    DataTableContainingSheep
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => (String)r["color"] == "black")
        .Sum(r => (Double)r["sheepId"]);
```

Comment: The DataTable is pure fiction. I just invented some example-code to help me explain what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Cool! Glad it was useful for you.